# Error with If-Else statement combine with Math in .bat file

Tags: math, if-statement, batch-file

It's supose to be simples, but i can't get it working ! Maybe someone could help...

I just need a program that check if '07503.csv' file exists, and than '07504.csv', '07505.csv'...until '07552.csv'. Here i'm supose to end the program (it's simplified so you can understand my problem).

This works:

```
SET angle=075
SET velocity=03
SET finalfilename=.csv

SET endofsequency=07552

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 

:loop

    SET currentsequency=%angle%%velocity%
    SET fullfilename=%currentsequency%%finalfilename%

    :CHECK_FILES
    IF EXIST %fullfilename% (
        ECHO FILE FOUND: %fullfilename% 
        GOTO :GO_TROUGHT 
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO FILE NOT FOUND: %fullfilename% 
        GOTO :WRITE_LOG 
    )

    :WRITE_LOG
    ECHO %time% missing: %fullfilename% 
    ECHO %time% missing: %fullfilename% >> FilesMissed.txt

    :GO_TROUGHT
    FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%velocity%") DO SET velocity=%%A
    SET /A velocity+=1
    SET velocity=000%velocity%
    SET velocity=%velocity:~-2%

    PAUSE

IF %currentsequency% NEQ %endofsequency% GOTO loop

:END

PAUSE
```

But with IF-ElSE statement does not:

```
SET angle=075
SET velocity=03
SET finalfilename=.csv

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 

:loop

    SET currentsequency=%angle%%velocity%
    SET fullfilename=%currentsequency%%finalfilename%

    :CHECK_FILES
    IF EXIST %fullfilename% (
        ECHO FILE FOUND: %fullfilename% 
        GOTO :GO_TROUGHT 
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO FILE NOT FOUND: %fullfilename% 
        GOTO :WRITE_LOG 
    )

    :WRITE_LOG
    ECHO %time% missing: %fullfilename% 
    ECHO %time% missing: %fullfilename% >> FilesMissed.txt

    :GO_TROUGHT
    IF "%velocity%" NEQ "52" (
        FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%velocity%") DO SET velocity=%%A
        SET /A velocity+=1
        SET velocity=000%velocity%
        SET velocity=%velocity:~-2%
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO :END
    )

    PAUSE

GOTO :loop

:END

PAUSE
```

My question is why? What's happening? Can't i use FOR inside a IF-ELSE ? Idk ...

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

Without reading closely - will using this help instead?

```
IF "%velocity%" EQU "52" goto :END
```

Looking a bit closer - it is an issue with delayed expansion.  You need to enable it and then use !variable! instead of %variable% when inside parenthesis.

EDIT: try this with delayed expansion.  The first line is changed, and the two last `SET velocity=` lines are changed.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET angle=075
SET velocity=03
SET finalfilename=.csv

SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 

:loop

    SET currentsequency=%angle%%velocity%
    SET fullfilename=%currentsequency%%finalfilename%

    :CHECK_FILES
    IF EXIST %fullfilename% (
        ECHO FILE FOUND: %fullfilename% 
        GOTO :GO_TROUGHT 
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO FILE NOT FOUND: %fullfilename% 
        GOTO :WRITE_LOG 
    )

    :WRITE_LOG
    ECHO %time% missing: %fullfilename% 
    ECHO %time% missing: %fullfilename% >> FilesMissed.txt

    :GO_TROUGHT
    IF "%velocity%" NEQ "52" (
        FOR /F "tokens=* delims=0" %%A IN ("%velocity%") DO SET velocity=%%A
        SET /A velocity+=1
        SET velocity=000!velocity!
        SET velocity=!velocity:~-2!
    ) ELSE (
        GOTO :END
    )

    PAUSE

GOTO :loop

:END

PAUSE
```

Comment: Thanks for answering!! As my example is simplified ( IF "%velocity%" EQU "52" goto :END ) will not help me because i WILL have to do some math operations inside the if-else statement.

Comment: I'm kinda n00b in batch and never used !variable! ... will i have just to change "%" for "!" when inside parenthesis? Is that a solution ?

Comment: See the edit I made to my answer.  BTW, if you used my first suggestion then you could do math without using parenthesis and it would work.

Comment: @FilipeWolve: To expand on the last comment, if you used `IF "%velocity%" EQU "52" goto :END` as suggested at the beginning of this answer, you wouldn't need to use ELSE with it and could simply put the calculations after the `IF` line (stripping them of the surrounding parentheses). They would be expanded "correctly" (i.e. as expected).

Answer (score 1):

This is the way I would do that:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion 

SET angle=075
SET "velocity=103"               // Will use just 2 last digits of velocity
SET finalfilename=.csv

SET "endVelocity=152"            // The same here...

SET /A numberOfValues=endVelocity - velocity + 1

for /L %%i in (1,1,%numberOfValues%) do (

    SET fullfilename=%angle%!velocity:~-2!%finalfilename%

    rem CHECK_FILES
    IF EXIST !fullfilename! (
        ECHO FILE FOUND: !fullfilename! 
    ) ELSE (
        ECHO FILE NOT FOUND: !fullfilename! 
        rem WRITE_LOG
        ECHO !time! missing: !fullfilename! 
        ECHO !time! missing: !fullfilename! >> FilesMissed.txt
    )

    SET /A velocity+=1

    PAUSE
)

PAUSE
```

Answer (score 1):

Like [@Aacini's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16995965/297408), the following uses a `FOR /L` loop, but the method is slightly different:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET angle=075
SET startvelocity=3
SET endvelocity=52
SET ext=.csv

SET /A startnum=1%angle%*100+startvelocity
SET /A endnum=1%angle%*100+endvelocity
FOR /L %%i IN (%startnum%,1,%endnum%) DO (
  SET "filename=%%i%ext%"
  SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
  IF EXIST !filename:~1! (
    ECHO FILE FOUND: !filename:~1!
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO FILE NOT FOUND: !filename:~1!
    SET "logline=!time! missing: !filename:~1!"
    ECHO !logline!
    ECHO !logline!>> FilesMissed.txt
  )
  ENDLOCAL
)
```

That is, the loop is iterating over values like

```
107503
107504
107505
...
```

The leading `1` was added to preserve the `0` before the `75`. (Leading `0`s are lost in arithmetical operations.)

In the loop body, the value of the loop variable is used to construct a file name:

```
107503.csv
107504.csv
...
```

The leading `1` is later dropped (using `~1` when expanding the name).

Additionally, in case what you are writing to the `FilesMissed.txt` file is always meant to be duplicated on the screen, I introduced a variable to show how you could make sure the contents is duplicated *exactly*, allowing you to make changes to the formatting of the line only once. (Could be especially useful if you intended to additionally write the same line to other files.)

Comment: +1 I like it! However: 1- You may drop the leading `1` just once. 2- Your code don't require the `SETLOCAL/ENDLOCAL` toggling because the expanded value of `%%i` are just digits.  ;-)